# What are the MonetDB equivalents of MySQL's least() and greatest()?

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min, monetdb

SQL queries reserve the names `min()` and `max()` for aggregate functions, leaving DBMSes to make other choices for *scalar* functions of the same functionality - the minimum or maximum value from a fixed-length list of arguments.

MySQL uses `least()` and `greatest()`, respectively, for that purpose; what are the MonetDB equivalents?

Answer (score 1):

The nearly-equivalent scalar functions in MonetDB are `sql_min()` and `sql_max()`. They're not actually equivalent since they're not variable-number-of-arguments - they each take exactly 2 arguments.

Note: The entire set of built-in functions - scalar and aggregate - are described in MonetDB's built-in `sys.functions` table.